# Shell Script to retrieve text from website

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

**Shell Script to retrieve text from website**

Is there a way to extract a specific part of a website and display it in a terminal? There is a couple of sections on [this site](https://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn) that displays a Username and Password for people to access their VPN (VPNBook). However they change the passwords, so I was wondering if a shell script could be made to access the website, extract the username and password fields, and displays it.

Right now the username and password fields are:

```
Username: vpnbook
Password: he2qv5h
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction to start this project, that would be great.

Comment: `curl http://www.example.com/vastly-insecure-VPN-credential-exposure` | grep -E '(username|password)'`?

Comment: running that command with my link replacing yours, only gives me this output: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10524    0 10524    0     0   5505      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  5504

Comment: Try @DopeGhoti's command but with `-E` replaced with `-Ei` so that the search for username and password is case insensitive.

Comment: It worked, but It looks like a mess on a terminal (it is displaying html code as well). Is there any way to make it just display the way they are displayed on the website?

Comment: To suppress the stat header add `-s` option  for silent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url='https://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn'
html=$( curl -# -L "${url}" 2> '/dev/null' )

username=$(
  <<< "${html}" \
  grep -P -o -e '(?<=<li>Username: <strong>)(.*?)(?=<\/strong><\/li>)' |
  head -n 1
)

password=$(
  <<< "${html}" \
  grep -P -o -e '(?<=<li>Password: <strong>)(.*?)(?=<\/strong><\/li>)' |
  head -n 1
)

printf '%s\n' "Username: ${username}" "Password: ${password}"
```

Comment: This works great, however it shows a progress bar above the output (something like: ####################100%) is there any way to not show that?

Comment: nevermind, i added a 'clear' after the url and html part and it got rid of it.

Comment: That progress bar is shown because of the curl command. It is send to stderr, not stdout, so it's safe to pipe its output to another command. Anyway, if you don't want to see that progress bar, you could add `2> '/dev/null'` to the curl command to send stderr to /dev/null. I've edited my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nxnev for the answer and explination. Now I just have to figure out what `grep` is doing lol. This script is really good though, so thanks again!